# How can I implement "onActivityResult" extending WebView Class

Tags: java, android, webview

I have an Activity and it extends WebView, how can I get resultCode when I Implement `(Activity).getContext().startActivityForResult(STRING, 1)`; ?

I tried and failed to implement `onActivityResult()`, How can I do that?
In normal Activity is easy to `@Override` the method `onActivityResult()`.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but I don't think you should extend WebView to use directly as your Activity. Try something like this instead:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebView = new MyWebView(this);
        setContentView(mWebView);
    }

    public class MyWebView extends WebView {
        public void startSomeActivity() {
            /* call startActivityForResult() here */
        }

        /* ... more code ... */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
        /* handle activity result here */
    }

    /* ... more code ... */
}
```

Notice that MyActivity is derived from Activity (so you can override `onActivityResult()` just like usual) and just uses the custom MyWebView (derived from WebView) in the `setContentView()` call in `onCreate()`.